# dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Please bear with me, newbie just learning the ropes.

I am getting the below message, when I try and run my app, it quiets, but then does let me re-open fine after the first quit.

I tried a few things and if I turn on if i 'activate breakpoints' it all works fine... 
Tried a few suggestions, 'deleting build folder', 'restarting xCode' nothing seems to work...

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
>   Referenced from:
>   /Volumes/MyBook/Apps/CToolBox/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CToolBox.app/CToolBox   Reason: image not found
>
> The Debugger has exited due to signal
>   5 (SIGTRAP).The Debugger has exited
>   due to signal 5 (SIGTRAP).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like its trying to find the UIKit Framework in the wrong location. It shouldn't be looking in system frameworks but in a path like this:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework
```

Get info on the UIKit framework within Xcode and see where it thinks the path to is at. If you installed in a non-standard location that might be your problem. You could also remove and readd the framework to try and change its path.

You should also check the configuration popup to make sure you're not trying to build for Cocoa.

Comment: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework

Comment: I did change the 'Set working directory to: Build Products directory' is this might have an impact.

Comment: Removing and including the framework (UIKit) back didn't fix the path issue

Answer (score 16):

Try this

Just delete your personal settings files for the project.Right click on .xcodeproj file and select show package contents .They will be username.mode1v3 and username.pbxuser. I didn’t figure out which file was the cause, but deleting them sorted it out.

Comment: Cool!  I deleted the .pbxuser file only - actually two of them, as there was no .mode1v3, and this took care of the problem!!  Thanks!

Comment: Tried this in Xcode 5.0.2 and now the project won't open.

Answer (score 3):

One other way I found today is, turning the Framework (in this case UIKit) in question as "optional". I hope you know how to do that :)

PS. I still wanna know the real reason of this abnormal linking failure? my code was working perfectly till today!

Answer (score 1):

You can also get this sort of error message trying to write a Mac OS app if you try to use a framework that's not available on your OS version, e.g. trying to write a MacOS SpriteKit app in Mountain Lion.